# PGF foreach: elegant way to handle empty list

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgffor

I am writing a simple animation in `beamer` using `tikz`.
The code is as follows

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]\relax
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
\only<+>{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.3]
        \node[circle,draw](x0){$x_0$};
        \foreach\x [remember=\x as \px (initially 0)] in {1,...,\i}{
            \node[draw, right=of x\px](P\x){$P[x_{\px}, x_{\x}]$};
            \node[circle,draw, right=of P\x](x\x){$x_{\x}$};
            \draw (P\x) edge (x\px) edge (x\x);
        }
        \node[draw, right=of x\i] (L) {$L[x_{\i}]$};
        \draw (L) edge (x\i) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the outer foreach starts from `\i=0`;
the inner one loops over a list `{1,...,\i}` which in the first iteration of the outer for rewrites to `{1,...,0}`.
Now the intended semantics of the inner for's list in the first iteration is the empty list but `PGF` interprets it as `{1,0}`, which generates the wrong picture in my example.
A bit surprisingly `{1,2,...,0}` is treated as `{1,2}`.

I solved the issue by extracting the first iteration outside the outer loop but I was wondering: is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Not an answer, but related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140776/why-does-foreach-x-in-0-1-0-perform-two-iterations-instead-of-one/140786#140786

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the package `xifthen`. It provides a function called `\ifthenelse{<if-clause>}{then-code}{else-code}`. In the above before calling the `\foreach`-loop there's a test if your `\i`-counter is bigger than `0`. If it is `0` no code will be run (empty `else-code`). If it is bigger your `\foreach`-loop is executed.

Hope this helps

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Use package xifthen
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\relax
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
\only<+>{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.3]
  \node[circle,draw](x0){$x_0$};
   \ifthenelse{\i > 0}{ % Check if \i bigger than 0, if true then run
    \foreach\x [remember=\x as \px (initially 0)] in {1,...,\i}{
     \node[draw, right=of x\px](P\x){$P[x_{\px}, x_{\x}]$};
     \node[circle,draw, right=of P\x](x\x){$x_{\x}$};
     \draw (P\x) edge (x\px) edge (x\x);
    }
   }{}; % Else run nothing
  \node[draw, right=of x\i] (L) {$L[x_{\i}]$};
  \draw (L) edge (x\i) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> Edit: As percusse stated in his comment, the check for `\i > 0` can also be done by the internals without using extra libraries (like xifthen). For example with `\ifnum`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\relax
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
\only<+>{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.3]
  \node[circle,draw](x0){$x_0$};
   \ifnum\i>0 % Check if \i bigger than 0 and if true run the \foreach
    \foreach\x [remember=\x as \px (initially 0)] in {1,...,\i}{
     \node[draw, right=of x\px](P\x){$P[x_{\px}, x_{\x}]$};
     \node[circle,draw, right=of P\x](x\x){$x_{\x}$};
     \draw (P\x) edge (x\px) edge (x\x);
    }
    \fi % End if-clause
  \node[draw, right=of x\i] (L) {$L[x_{\i}]$};
  \draw (L) edge (x\i) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pgf also has if then functionality.

Comment: The `\ifnum` solution is my preferred one. However I was hoping there was a way to tell PGF to generate the empty list for the inner loop on the first iteration. At least this avoids code duplication.