# tikz: make counter only increase

Tags: tikz-pgf

In most programming languages that I know of, counters increase unless told to do otherwise. For example the statement

```
for i = 1 to 0 do { print "hi" }
```

would do nothing.

But in tikz, this is not the case. Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {-1,...,3}
  {
    \node at (\i,-2) {$\leq$ \i};
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\i} {\node at (\i,\j) {\j};};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

I want this to print the natural numbers less than \i for each \i, but it prints

[image]

adding a superfluous 0 and -1.

I know I can fix this with an \ifthenelse, but I was hoping to avoid that. I'd like a macro or an easy way to have the usual programming paradigm of counters that increase (unless told to do otherwise).

Thanks!

Comment: {0,...,-4} counts backwards, so runs through 0, -1, -2, -3, -4. This is documented. The question is what {0,1,...,-4} should do.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140776/why-does-foreach-x-in-0-1-0-perform-two-iterations-instead-of-one

Answer (score 3):

`{0,...,-4}` counts backwards, so runs through 0, -1, -2, -3, -4. 
`{0,1,...,n}` executes the code as least for the first two numbers, see e.g. [Why does \foreach \x in {0,1,...,0}{} perform two iterations (instead of one)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140776/why-does-foreach-x-in-0-1-0-perform-two-iterations-instead-of-one)

You could use an expl3-step function instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,expl3}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\intstepvariable\int_step_variable:nnnNn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \intstepvariable {-1}{1}{3}\i
  {
    \node at (\i,-2) {$\leq$ \i};
    \intstepvariable {0}{1}{\i}\j
     {
      \node at (\i,\j) {\j};
     }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]